# Laplace's equation in cylinder — does a solution exist?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, cylindrical-coordinates

> **7.9.2. (c)** Solve Laplace's equation inside a semicircular cylinder, subject to the boundary conditions 
>  $$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} u (r, \theta, 0) = 0, \quad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} u (r, \theta, H) = 0, \quad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta} u (r, 0, z) = 0, \quad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta} u (r, \pi, z) = 0, \quad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r} u (a, \theta, z) = \beta (\theta, z) $$ Under what condition does a solution exist?

---

How can I know a solution exists? My intuition tells me flux in should equal flux out, but I don't know how can I get a mathematical condition for that.

Comment: Please provide the source of the screenshot. Has Haberman written only one thing?

Comment: Despite the way this has been posed, I find this a worthwhile post. @Gonçalo, you could be a tiny bit more explicit here.